# Hadoop approach to outputting millions of small binary/image files

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, reduce

I need to process and manipulate many images in a Hadoop job, the input will be over the network, slow downloads using the `MultiThreadedMapper`.

But what is the best approach to the reduce ouput? I think I should write the raw binary image data into a sequence file, transfer those files to their eventual home, then write a small app to extract the individual images from the `SequenceFile` into individual JPGs and GIFs.

Or is there a better option to consider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you feel up to it (or maybe through some Googleing you can find an implementation), you could write a FileOutputFormat which wraps a FSDataOutputStream with a [ZipOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html), giving you a Zip file for each reducer (and thus saving you the effort in writing seq file extraction program.

Don't be daunted by writing your own OutputFormat, it really isn't that difficult (and much easier than writing custom InputFormats which have to worry about splits). In fact here's a starting point - you just need to implement the write method:

```
// Key: Text (path of the file in the output zip)
// Value: BytesWritable - binary content of the image to save
public class ZipFileOutputFormat extends FileOutputFormat<Text, BytesWritable> {
    @Override
    public RecordWriter<Text, BytesWritable> getRecordWriter(
            TaskAttemptContext job) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Path file = getDefaultWorkFile(job, ".zip");

        FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(job.getConfiguration());

        return new ZipRecordWriter(fs.create(file, false));
    }

    public static class ZipRecordWriter extends
            RecordWriter<Text, BytesWritable> {
        protected ZipOutputStream zos;

        public ZipRecordWriter(FSDataOutputStream os) {
            zos = new ZipOutputStream(os);
        }

        @Override
        public void write(Text key, BytesWritable value) throws IOException,
                InterruptedException {
            // TODO: create new ZipEntry & add to the ZipOutputStream (zos)
        }

        @Override
        public void close(TaskAttemptContext context) throws IOException,
                InterruptedException {
            zos.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi ,I have used exactly same code but for me it is not working .Still getting same output format .